# No Brasil, pode uma vogal ser nasalada por influência da palavra seguinte?

Tags: português-brasileiro, fonologia

É sabido que em grande parte do Brasil as vogais tónicas são nasaladas quando seguidas de consoante nasal (*m, n* ou *nh*) na sílaba seguinte. Por exemplo,

pronunciado (quase?) como

- *cana*         →        *cãna*,
- *remo*        →        *rẽmo*,
- *ponho*      →        *põnho*.

Ao que parece, a vogal tónica nesta situação sofre alguma influência nasal em todo o lado, mas o artigo sobre [Portuguese pholonology (Wikipedia em inglês)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology#Further_notes_on_the_oral_vowels) diz que essa influência é quase inexistente em Portugal, São Paulo e sul do Brasil.

A minha pergunta é se também há influência nasal quando a consoante nasal está na palavra seguinte, como:

pronunciado (quase?) como

- *Zé Manel*       →        *Zẽ Manel* ?
- *Zé Nota*        →        *Zẽ Nota* ?
- *está mal*       →        *estã mal* ?

Ou ainda, o *Zé* em *Zé Manel* ou *Zé Nota* é diferente do de *Zé Carlos*? Ou *vi muito depressa* confunde-se com *vim muito depressa* (mesmo que não se fale muito depressa)?

Comment: A palavra remo (remar), não é realmente nasalada como seria o caso de: cap**im**.  E a cana-de-açucar também não. po**nho** por definição sim. :) como risonho e canhota, por exemplo. Qualquer palavra com nho ou nha, sim. As outras, não.

Answer (score 2):

Não, não consigo encontrar nenhum exemplo em que isso acontece, ao menos nos falares com que tenho familiaridade.

> Zé em Zé Manel ou Zé Nota é diferente do de Zé Carlos

Não, o "Zé" é pronunciado marcadamente separado da palavra seguinte.

> *vi muito depressa* confunde-se com *vim muito depressa* (mesmo que não se fale muito depressa)

Talvez, mas principalmente pelos "i"s serem, para mim, iguais nos dois casos.

Comment: Um é / i /, o outro é / ĩ /. Tu és daqueles que nasalas *remo* → *rẽmo*? Ou distingues bem quem nasala de quem não nasala. Eu antes de ler sobre isso nunca tinha notado nada. Confirma-se o que diz a Wikipedia, que em São Paulo quase não se nasala? Creio que já ouvi o contrário…

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, digo "_rêmo_". Sobre São Paulo acho difícil dizer com certeza, mas também não creio que se nasale muito menos. A usuária megskae, de SP, [pronuncia](https://forvo.com/word/cama/#pt_br) "cama" com o primeiro "a" fechado — apesar de que aos meus ouvidos os áudios de Portugal também, então talvez esse seja uma mau exemplo.

Comment: Calma: uma coisa é *rêmo*, outra é *rẽmo*; não é só uma questão de timbre aberto versus fechado. Por exemplo, *cêdo* e *sendo = sẽdo* têm ambos E fechado, mas num é oral, no outro é nasal. Em *c**a**ma*, a questão é se o primeiro A é simplesmente fechado como em *cada* ou se é nasal como em *canta = cãta*.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, sim, em "cama" é anasalado. Fico imaginando se â e ã são quase sempre o mesmo no meu dialeto...

Comment: O A é capaz de não ser bom teste. O meu primeiro A de *cada* é fechado, mas o teu é capaz de ser aberto. No E (se o E de *f**e**no* é como o de *c**ê**do* fechado oral, ou o de *s**en**do = s**ẽ**do* nasal) e O (se o O de *l**o**na* é como o de *l**ô**ba* fechado oral ou o de *l**om**ba = l**õ**ba* nasal) é que se vê bem se h

Comment: Eu francamente não entendo: cama, não, caminho, sim. Cana, não, canhota sim. E assim pra frente.

Comment: @Jacinto Me baseando nessa [lista de símbolos fonéticos](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/escolar-ingles/transcricao-fonetica-do-portugues/) para o pt-BR, há 4 a's: os abertos /a/ ("caro") quase igual ao /ə/ ("janel*a*") (citação: "pode ser substituído por [a], sem prejuízo para a comunicação."); e os fechados /^/ "levemente nasalizado" ("cama", "cana", "cânhamo") e o nasal /ã/ ("canto", "órfã"), mas eu francamente vejo pouca ou nenhuma diferença entre esses dois últimos, não acho, por exemplo, que o "a" de "cânhamo" seja menos nasal que o de "canto".

Comment: @Jacinto Quanto ao "e", talvez seja mesmo melhor para distinguir. Acho que, grosso modo, anasalamos mais, mas é possível distinguir o "e" de "cêdo" do de "sendo" e este último é igual (muito anasalado) ao de "feno".

Comment: @Lambie Para mim ambos "cama" e "caminho" têm o "a" anasalado; idem para "cana" e "canhota". Cf. a [lista de símbolos fonéticos](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/escolar-ingles/transcricao-fonetica-do-portugues/) do Michaelis.

Comment: Claro: cami**nho**, o nho é sempre nasalado. Mas cama, não. Todo m em português não é nasalado.  Fala a palavra cama uma ou duas vezes. Não tem nenhum som "nasal". O air sai na primeira sílaba: CA e depois na segunda: MA sem passar pela nariz. Nada está acontencendo na nariz na palavra cama ou camera. cana de açucar é igual. Não passa pela nariz, gente. :)

Comment: Acabo de falar com dois brasileiros. Os dois me disseram que cama e camera não são nasalidas. Claro, cante, sim.

Comment: @Lambie O Brasil tem uma diversidade de sotaques. O Michaelis descreve o "a" de "cama" e "cana" como "levemente nasalizado", e é assim que experiencio também, em mim mesmo e em muita gente que conheço — penso que anasalo em algum grau quase todo "a" fechado.

Comment: This is a really complicated subject. That said, the Brazilian Portuguese pronunciation of cama and the Iberian Portuguese pronunciation of cama can give the latter a distinctive nasal feature that is not heard as strongly in the former.

Comment: @stafusa, não sei se isto te interessa saber, mas acho que faço diferença entre as tais vogal levemente anasalada e nasal. Falo /kɐ̃ma/ (cama), /kɐ̃na/ (cana) e /kɐ̃ɲamʊ/ (cânhamo), mas falo /kɐ̃ŋtʊ/ (canto). De *órfã*, já posso dizer tanto /ɔɹfɐ̃/ quanto /ɔɹfɐ̃ŋ/, mas sempre considerei /ɔɹfɐ̃/ mais correto, enquanto dizer /ɔɹfɐ̃ŋ/ é força de hábito. Por isto, para mim «vim depressa» é /vĩŋd͡ʒɪprɛsa/ e «vi depressa» é /vid͡ʒɪprɛsa/, então, não faço confusão entre as frases. Para mim, «pinta como eu pinto» não tem graça — *com * é /kõŋ/ e *como* é /komʊ/. Sou de São Paulo, SBC.